# Getting 404 error when including image name with underscore

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I'm using Google Maps and JavaScript to create markers with a custom image. The custom image has a **name with an underscore** in it, like ab_c.png. When I try to access it in a browser, I get a **404 Not Found error** for that marker. When I change it back to abc.png, the image works.

For example, this does not work:

```
imageChoiceArr["girl"] = "tre_e.png";
```

but this does:

```
imageChoiceArr["girl"] = "tree.png";
```

Why isn't it working for images with underscores in their filenames?

Comment: So you've tried just going to the URL in your browser and seeing if that's the correct one?

Comment: There is no issues with underscores in names. The image most likely just doesn't exist.

Comment: Yeah. I checked. It's actually working now with the underscores. When I originally checked under Network tab (Chrome devtools), it was sending a GET for the "abc" file when it was actually named "ab_c" in the directory and in the code. I don't think it's a user error, since I had someone else experience the same. Maybe something with XAMPP.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use hyphens instead of underscores?  It could be that underscores are stripped.

Check out [this](http://blog.woorank.com/2013/04/underscores-in-urls-why-are-they-not-recommended/).  Not quite the same but related.  From the page:

> Google has clearly stated that when it comes to URL structure, using hyphens rather than underscores makes it much easier for them to identify what the page is about.

Based on this, my thought was that if Google is recommending hyphens over underscores, it's possible the Google Maps API likewise shuns underscores.

Comment: Ok, I think it was something with the cache. Underscores are now working. When I originally checked via Chrome devtool, under the Network tab, the browser was looking for "abc" when the file was called "ab_c". Now it's looking for "ab_c" and does find it. I'm also using XAMPP.

Comment: Weird. It might come back. Maybe better to use hyphens.